# PandasのDataFrameで歯抜けになってるデータの整合性を合わせたい

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

いつもお世話になっております。
Pandas.DataFrameで `display(df)` などでデータを見た時に
次のようになっているデータがあります。

|  | id | before | after | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 20 | 2000/01 |
| 2 | B | 30 | NaN | 2001/01 |
| 3 | B | NaN | 40 | 2001/01 |
| 4 | C | NaN | NaN | 2002/01 |

これを下記のようにしたいのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか。

|  | id | before | after | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 20 | 2000/01 |
| 2 | B | 30 | 40 | 2001/01 |
| 3 | C | NaN | NaN | 2002/01 |

- 多分 `id` と `date` はペアになってる...はず
- before/afterについて、片方がNaNの場合、一緒にまとめたい
- `id=C` のように両方NaNだったり、片方のデータしか存在しないレコードもある

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問に記載されているデータフレームの場合には以下で充分ですが、実際に処理するデータフレームで期待する結果が得られるかどうかは、、、おそらく期待外れの結果になるかと思います。

```py
dfx = df.groupby(['id', 'date'], group_keys=False)\
        .apply(lambda x: x.bfill().ffill().drop_duplicates())\
        .reset_index(drop=True)
               
print(dfx)
```

| id | before | after | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 20 | 2000/01 |
| B | 30 | 40 | 2001/01 |
| C | nan | nan | 2002/01 |